# How can i get the updated cart session array and display it in another php file AJAX

Tags: php, arrays, ajax, cart

**AJAX**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//remove product from cart
                $(".delete-product-cart").click(function(e){

             var id = $(this).data('id');
             $.ajax({
                 url: "remove_from_cart.php",
                 type: "GET", //send it through get method
                 data: {
                     id: id,
                 },
                 success: function(response) {


                 },
                 error: function(xhr) {
                     //Do Something to handle error
                 }
             });

                });
});
```

**//remove_from_cart.php**

```
<?php
// start session
session_start();

// get the product id
$id = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : "";


// remove the item from the array
unset($_SESSION['cart'][$id]);
?>
```

**// Then i have the cart.php where i press the button to delete a product in a while loop** The session cart inside the FOREACH is what's important to update the product WITHOUT reloading the page i guess. So how will THIS session cart will be updated without cart.php reloading??

```
if(count($_SESSION['cart'])>0){

    // get the product ids
    $ids = array();
    foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $id=>$value){
        array_push($ids, $id);
    }

    $stmt=$product->readByIds($ids);


    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

product with ID here

    }
}
```

Comment: when you say it does not work, what result are you getting and what are you expecting instead?

Comment: @ArSeN Thanks for your answer and time. 1.I am getting no result on `$("#getArrayAndPutInsidePHP").html(array);` 2. I want to put the array from AJAX in a OTHER php file: `$_SESSION['cart'] = cart session array(from AJAX).`. So then the CART SESSION will be updated after click

Comment: @ArSeN Oh wait i got result now. But this is JSON.stringify how do i revert back to normal and do i have to use `json_decode` again for to put it in a PHP session?

Comment: @ArSeN Are you still there i am stuck with this. I just want the updated cart array to work and that i can use it inside another php file. So that the cart session will update without reloading page

Comment: I would like to help you but I don't understand the logic of what you try. So you have a $_session['cart'] that holds multiple id's -> you whant to remove an id from the session with an ajax request -> ... I'm not sure what you try to do next

Comment: @Baracuda078 I want the cart session to update when i click DELETE product. So then the product will remove WITHOUT reloading. I have the updated JSON stringify CART SESSION from AJAX now. But i don't know how to send that Jquery Array from AJAX back to PHP and REPLACE the original cart SESSION. So then the Product will  be removed and gone when i CLICK remove. Thanks for your time and answer!

Comment: @Baracuda078 Can you please help i don't know what to do. Am 6 hours on this without solution.

Comment: the ajax call to your php script will remove it from the session. You dont need to send something else again to php. I gues you whant to remove the html of that product from the cart

Comment: @Baracuda078 Yes i understand that. But after remove product click. The product is not removed, only AFTER reloading the page. So i have a session CART inside `cart.php` (where i delete products) and i have the `remove_from_product.php`. The last PHP file i use for AJAX. But how can the `cart.php` SESSION change LIKE the PHP file from AJAX? That's why i thought i had to CATCH the updated SESSION cart ARRAY from  `remove_from_product.php` And then use it, but that's where i got stuck. Can you explain me please how the AJAX php file can be synced with the `cart.php` ? Thanks for your time

Comment: Sorry for asking all those things but i try to understand your workflow. so on cart.php you see all the products in your cart (I gues you have every thing in one file, first your php code then your html and in your html you have your jacasxript with the ajax function to remove products) and after you clicked the button to remove an product you remove it from your session and then you whant to remove the product from your page when you got the response back from your ajax call

Comment: @Baracuda078 I updated my question with CODE. It should be understandable for you know. Let me know oke? I am gratefull for your time that your trying to help me.

Comment: @Baracuda078 Did you read my question all over again? I retyped it. For making it understandable for you. I am still trying alot of things but i am still stuck. This is the second day i am trying this.......... Let me know if you dont understand something

Comment: @Gester I posted some code that will help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will help you. I used as manny of your own code. 
There are many points of improvements but i guess this is a learning project of yours

```
<?php
/**
 * remove_from_cart.php
 */
// Test if the script gets loaded by a POST request
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' && isset($_POST['id'])) {

  session_start();
  $id = (int)$_POST['id'];
  // remove the item from the array
  unset($_SESSION['cart'][$id]);

}


/**
 * cart.php
 */
if (isset($_SESSION['cart']) && count($_SESSION['cart']) > 0) {

  // get the product ids
  // Wy do this? your session is already an array with the ids
  $ids = array();
  // And here you add the key of the array to ids and not the product_id so you will get the wrong products
  foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $id => $value) {
    array_push($ids, $id);
  }

  $stmt = $product->readByIds($_SESSION['cart']); // Instead of $ids you can add the session

  // this works, but add your fetch in your readByIds method to keep your code cleaner and return the array with products
  while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    ?>
    <div class="product-row">
      <p><?= $row['product_name'];?></p>
      <p><?= $row['product_price'];?></p>
      <button type="button" class="delete-product-cart" data-id="<? $row['product_id']; ?>">Remove</button>
    </div>
    <?php

  }
} else {
  // Cart session doesnt exist or is empty
  // Let the user know the his cart is empty
}
?>

<script>
  $(function () {
    // Remove product from cart
    $(".delete-product-cart").click(function (e) {
      var
        button = $(this),
        product_id = button.data('id');

      $.ajax({
        url: "remove_from_cart.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
          id: product_id,
        },
        beforeSend: function() {
          // Disable the button, to prevent duplicate request
          button.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        },
        success: function (data) { // Response data is not used now
          button.parent().fadeOut(300, function () {
            button.remove();
          });
        },
        complete: function() {
          // Make the button enabled again, for when the delete function didnt work the button can be pressed again
          button.removeAttr('disabled');
        }
        error: function () {
          //Do Something to handle error
        }
      });
    });

  });

</script>
```

Comment: Yes i realised yesterday it was not possible on WHAT i wanted with PHP only. So i also used remove() with Jquery , now it removes the product with Jquery. But i thought it could be possible with only PHP but i learned that it could not....

Thanks for your time and answer, have a nice day/night!